# Issue with variables in insert statement in python 3

Tags: string, list, variables, insert, python-3.6

This is regarding hackerrank problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem .Below is my implemented code. I am facing issue with the insert statement as it is asking for at least two variables. I tried converting user input to list and then inputting into the insert statement. It's throwing an error. Please help!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    l=[]
    for _ in range(N):
        line = input().split()
        cmd = line[0]
        args= line[1:]
        """if cmd!= "print":
            cmd += "(" + ",".join(args)+")"""
        x = ",".join(map(str,args))
        if cmd == "insert":
            l.insert(x)
        elif cmd == "remove":
            l.remove(x)
        elif cmd == "append":
            l.append(x)
        elif cmd == "sort":
            l.sorted(x)
        elif cmd == "pop":
            l.pop(x)
        elif cmd =="reverse":
            l.reverse(x)
        else:
            print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Insert** in Lists:

Insert is used to `insert` a given value at particular index of list. It expects two arguments.

Definition from **python.org**:

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of
>   the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the
>   front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to
>   a.append(x).

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing error because, Insert method has no overload with only one argument.
Insert method has a overload which takes two arguments,

1. Index
2. Item

In the problem, you have to get the index based on the input.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    list = []
    for i in range(n):
        userinput = input().strip().split()
        cmd = userinput[0]
        if(len(userinput) == 3):
            index = int(userinput[1])
            val = int(userinput[2])
        elif(len(userinput) == 2):
            val = int(userinput[1])

        if(cmd == 'insert'):
            list.insert(index, val)
        elif(cmd == 'append'):
            list.append(val)
        elif(cmd == 'print'):
            print(list)
        elif(cmd=='remove' and val in list):
            list.remove(val)
        elif(cmd=='pop' and len(list) > 0):
            list.pop()
        elif(cmd=='reverse'):
            list = list[::-1]
        elif(cmd=='sort'):
            list.sort()
```

This code will solve your problem.